# Updating WordPress and plugins without DB back-up?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, updates

I am currently working on a website that runs by WordPress. I need to update WordPress and the plugins on the website. I only got FTP details.

From earlier cases I learned that updating can ruin your website, so I don't want to take any risks on this project.

I read about backing up FTP and your DB, but I do not have access to the DB. My question is; **can I update WordPress and the plugins safely with only a back-up from the FTP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a DB backup with the plugin `adminer`

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/adminer/

**And one information more:**

By the way - the DB access details are in the wp-config.php file.